# get_current_screen() inside add_action('admin_menu')

Tags: screen-options

I am successfully using get_current_screen(); to get the post_type to decide whether to manipulate a meta box or not.

I also need to use it in:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'infographicMetaBox');

function infographicMetaBox() {
    // ...
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if('post' != $screen->post_type)
        return;
    // ...
}
```

however it doesn't seem to be available in that hook function (maybe being called to early?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish but you seem to be dealing with meta boxes. If so there are a number of meta box specific hooks.

> ```
> do_action('add_meta_boxes', $post_type, $post);
> do_action('add_meta_boxes_' . $post_type, $post);
>
> do_action('do_meta_boxes', $post_type, 'normal', $post);
> do_action('do_meta_boxes', $post_type, 'advanced', $post);
> do_action('do_meta_boxes', $post_type, 'side', $post);
> ```
>
> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php#L165

As well as the `admin_head*` hooks

> ```
> do_action("admin_head-$hook_suffix");
> do_action('admin_head');
> ```
>
> http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L68

All of which run after `global $current_screen` is set here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/admin-header.php#L18

Comment: admin_head hook seems to be working great for this. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is too early. Check http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen for examples of usage.

Comment: What are my options then? I have code to query a database to populate a metabox, but I only want it happening on the main post new/edit screens instead of making a wasteful db call every page load.

Comment: You can hook your function to anything that comes *after* `admin_init`.  Perhaps `admin_head` would work. [Here's a (probably incomplete) list of actions run during an Admin page load.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_an_Admin_Page_Request)

Comment: Hook your function to edit_post. Function will have one parameter $id which is post_id. Use get_post_type( $id ) to determine post's type and go from there.